# initialize java int 2d array from string

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a simple 2d array

```
// Creating and Initializing 2D array
        int a[][] = {{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}};
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<2; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

works everything fine. But how can I initialize the array when the content is dynamic and coming from a variable?

```
String arrContent = "{{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}}"; //actually a method readContentFromFile(); will deliver the content
int a[][] = arrContent;
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunatelty this is not possible without parsing the `String`, which is rather complicated in this case. If you have the possibility to change the file's content to json, using a json parser will be the quickest solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input stream can be parsed using `String::split` and Stream API:

1. get rows splitting by comma between a pair of `},{`
2. remove redundant curly brackets using `String::replaceAll`
3. for each row, split by comma, convert numbers to int `Stream::mapToInt` and get array
4. collect to multidimensional array with `Stream::toArray`

```java
String arrContent = "{{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}}";

int[][] arr = Arrays.stream(arrContent.split("\\}\\s*,\\s*\\{")) //1
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[{}]", ""))                          //2
    .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s*,\\s*"))                //3
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()
    )
    .toArray(int[][]::new);                                      //4
    
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Output

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

---

Another approach could be to use JSON parser, however, initial  input string needs to be modified to become a valid JSON array (curly brackets `{}` have to be replaced with the square ones `[]` using simpler `String::replace(char old, char rep)`):

```java
String arrContent = "{{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}}";

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

int[][] arr = om.readValue(
        arrContent.replace('{', '[')
                  .replace('}', ']'),
        int[][].class);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));

// output
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to provide a little bit modified solution using simple regexp just in case anybody would prefer doing it this way:

```
String input = "{{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{[0-9,]+}");
int[][] array = pattern.matcher(input).results()
    .map(matchResult -> matchResult.group().replaceAll("[{}]", ""))
    .map(numberAsText -> Arrays.stream(numberAsText.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Just as the others pointed out - if you have the possibility to change shape of input - I would also advice to use JSON's array and parse it using JSON parser which would make it much easier and more clean.